Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed, while compiling a JavaFX project in Maven
Recently I encountered an issue with the IntelliJ Idea, while I tried to compile an JavaFx project.
Here's the error message (Stack Trace):
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@21/21.0.3/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=60420:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/13/javafx-controls-13.jar:/Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/13/javafx-graphics-13.jar:/Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/13/javafx-base-13.jar:/Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/13/javafx-fxml-13.jar -p /Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/13/javafx-graphics-13-mac.jar:/Users/nemethhunor/IdeaProjects/untitled/target/classes:/Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/13/javafx-controls-13-mac.jar:/Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/13/javafx-base-13-mac.jar:/Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/13/javafx-fxml-13-mac.jar -m org.example/org.example.App
Loading library prism_es2 from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib: dlopen(/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_es2.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2025)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:214)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:194)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:135)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:53)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$0(ES2Pipeline.java:68)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Loading library prism_sw from resource failed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib: dlopen(/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/nemethhunor/.openjfx/cache/13/libprism_sw.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:331)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:197)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:139)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2418)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:852)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:2025)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.installLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:214)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFromResource(NativeLibLoader.java:194)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:135)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:53)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    ... 2 more

What should I do? The system, what I use, is Mac OS 14.5 on ARM architecture.
Thanks for your answers!
I tried to install SDKMAN, but without much success.
I reinstalled javafx-sdk-23.

install jdk with javafx (zulu 21.0.4.fx-zulu) command: 'sdk install java 21.0.4.fx-Zulu`

Thanks! It solved my issue!

Because you have an M series Mac, whichever JavaFX version you use, ensure it is the Mac aarch64 architecture version and not the Mac x64 architecture version.  Currently, you are trying to use a JavaFX version compiled only for Intel/AMD processors and not for Apple's M processors, and the Apple machine cannot process the x64 code.
If using the JavaFX SDK from Gluon, then choose 23:macOS:aarch64:SDK from the drop-downs.  Adjust the version number to use the latest stable version or long-term service (LTS) version as desired.
If using Maven, it should pick up the correctly classified version for you (mac-aarch64), but only in later JavaFX versions (e.g. 21+).
I don't know anything about SDKMAN, so can't advise how to use JavaFX with that.
In your question, you mentioned that you "installed javafx-sdk-23", but the execution has JavaFX 13 sourced from Maven, /Users/nemethhunor/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/13/javafx-controls-13.jar, so it is trying to use the older JavaFX version, not the newer one.
You were using a version of JavaFX that is 10 versions behind what you thought you were. There was no support for M series Macs (aarch64 processors) in JavaFX 13, as M series Macs did not exist at the time.  Such an obsolete version of JavaFX could never work on your machine.
